# SimpleDateFormat incompatible types

Tags: java

I have to build a program where administration can call onto things of a certain period (choosing a start and end date and the period would be in between those).

Deciding wether a date falls in between the period to actually show the right information I want to convert a string to a date and then to milliseconds.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
// instance variables
private String Consumer;
private Order order;
private String date;

/**
 * Fill in the name of the Consumer and the order number.
 * Fill in the date/day in dd-MM-yyyy formate please.
 */
public Customer(String Consumer, String date, Order order)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.Consumer = Consumer;
    this.order = order;
    this.date = date;
}

/**
 * Get the startDate
 */
public void getDate()
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date newDate = sdf.parse(date);
}
```

Now I get the error "incompatible types; You wrote a String where an int was expected.). Isn't it supposed to convert a string? Why does it expect int? The error lies on the "sdf.parse(date);" part.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I do not see any error, except you have to surround the sdf.parse(date) with try catch

Comment: Apparently I forgot to import the java.util.Date and then didn't try / catch. Simple errors... -.-